# React optimize re-rendering by waiting for a script to load and then make API calls?

Tags: react-hooks

I have a hook called `useText` which waits for a script to load into my html DOM:
`<script src='...' .../>`

useText implementation is something like this:

```
export const useText = (key: TranslationKey): string => {
  const [isScriptEnabled, setScriptEnabled] = useState(false)
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    scriptExists() // this function also sets a global variable window.scriptExists
    //@ts-ignore
    if (window.scriptExists != null) return setScriptEnabled(window.scriptExists)

    const setScriptAfterLoad = () => {
      //@ts-ignore
      if (window.scriptExists != null) return setScriptExists(window.oneLinkTranslationExists)
      else setScriptExists(scriptExists())
      window.removeEventListener('load', setScriptAfterLoad)
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', setScriptAfterLoad)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('load', setScriptAfterLoad)
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isScriptEnabled) setText('')
    else tLazy(key).then((result) => setText(key))
  }, [isScriptEnabled, key])
  return text
}
```

Now this useText is being used at 60 other places and for each time I invoke the script it needs to check whether the script with source '...' exists or not:

```
document?.querySelector?.(`script[src*="${scriptUrlSubstring}"]`) != null
```

Now the problem is I am not sure how long would it take for this script to load and so I am adding 'load' event listener which is propogating to all 60 places causing a huge number of re-renders.

I wanted to optimize it further and wanted to know what would be the best way to handle such situations.